# UnrecognisedPropertyException and HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using RestTemplate.exchange() with Spring spring 3.x and Jackson 2.x and I am getting the below exception eventhough the mentioned variables in the exception is exactly same as in my POJO Product. But when I used the same with  spring 4 and Jackson 2.6.3 the issue is resolved. Can someone please tell in why i am not able to get the response with the help of Spring 3 and Jackson 2.x as I dont want to increase my Spring and Jackson version.

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "nonDiscountedPrice"   at
>   [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@4172607; line: 1,
>   column: 3594] (through reference chain:
>   com.java.LoginDisplayRS["customer"]->com.java.Customer["rentalOptions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.java.Product["nonDiscountedPrice"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "nonDiscountedPrice" (class com.java.Product), not
>   marked as ignorable (45 known properties:

Comment: Can you try adding @JsonIgnoreProperty on the field nonDiscountedPrice in the product class and test ?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting nonDiscountedPrice is a required field for me. Can you please tell if there anything we have to do with Spring and Jackson lower versions.

Comment: Not sure . Did u try the property Json ignore and see what happens.